# bootstrap tooltip is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using bootstrap in IE but its not working

Here is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
   <head> 
     <meta charset="utf-8"> 
     <title>Twitter Bootstrap Popover Example</title> 
       <meta name="description" content="This is an example to create Popover with     Twitter Bootstrap.">
  <link href="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
   </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
     <h2>Example of creating Popover with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
      <div class="well">
     <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
   </div>
      </div>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
     <script src="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
     <script src="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").tooltip({
        'selector': '',
        'placement': 'bottom'
    });
    console.log("jimmy");
 });
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Run this in any version of IE any you will get error in you console.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'tooltip'

Comment: @downvoter please care to explain .

Comment: The tooltip function pointer is not loaded. Check your js files exist and are loading without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http links to twitter bootstrap seem to be removed. It's not working anymore, (it used to work some time in history) **because Twitter removed the bootstrap http links**. You should try jQuery tooltip instead.

**http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js**

Comment: its Jquery-Ui tooltip , i clearly mentioned that i am using bootstrap tooltip

Comment: right. But your src files refer to nowhere. Your html doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: ok i will fix that , but i assume some surprising answer for bootstrap .